# How to get a completely clean python environment with miniconda?

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I have tried:

```
conda create --name Leaf python==3.6.5
```

And if I do `conda list`
I can find:

```
# packages in environment at /home/roychang/miniconda3/envs/Leaf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0  
openssl                   1.0.2o               h14c3975_1  
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0  
python                    3.6.5                hc3d631a_2  
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4  
setuptools                40.0.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.24.0               h84994c4_0  
tk                        8.6.7                hc745277_3  
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2
```

But if I try to run some script which use some package didn't in this list (like kivy).
I think it shouldn't work, but it did!

So does MiniConda auto fetch the package from the origin python root?
How could I get a completely clean python environment with MiniConda?

**UPDATE:**

Seems that I didn't explain well, I had activated that environment and what I got after doing `conda list` was the result showing above.

I could run this script when I activated the environment, although I didn't install kivy under this environment. I only installed kivy to the origin python before I installed MiniConda.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

And what else I found is if I try `which python`, it showed:

```
(Leaf) roychang@ThinkPad-T480:~$ which python
/home/roychang/miniconda3/bin/python
```

After I deactivated the environment and did `which python` again I got the same result.
Is this expected? I think it should use different python in different environment.

`conda list` in default environment (I found Kivy isn't here):

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h9745a5d_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h0f667ec_1
conda                     4.5.4                    py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
cryptography              2.2.2            py36h14c3975_0
idna                      2.6              py36h82fb2a8_1
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0
openssl                   1.0.2o               h20670df_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h0a5515d_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hf9f622e_1
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0
python                    3.6.5                hc3d631a_2
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4
requests                  2.18.4           py36he2e5f8d_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.37          py36h14c3975_2
setuptools                39.2.0                   py36_0
six                       1.11.0           py36h372c433_1
sqlite                    3.23.1               he433501_0
tk                        8.6.7                hc745277_3
urllib3                   1.22             py36hbe7ace6_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2
```

`pip list` in default environment (kivy is found here):

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
asn1crypto             0.24.0
bcrypt                 3.1.4
bitarray               0.8.3
boto                   2.49.0
boto3                  1.7.74
botocore               1.10.74
certifi                2018.4.16
cffi                   1.11.5
chardet                3.0.4
click                  6.7
coloredlogs            10.0
conda                  4.5.4
cryptography           2.3
Cython                 0.28.2
docutils               0.14
ffmpeg-python          0.1.15
ffmpy                  0.2.2
future                 0.16.0
humanfriendly          4.16.1
idna                   2.7
jmespath               0.9.3
Kivy                   1.10.1
Kivy-Garden            0.1.4
mysql-connector-python 8.0.11
numpy                  1.15.0
paramiko               2.4.1
Pillow                 5.2.0
pip                    10.0.1
protobuf               3.6.0
pyasn1                 0.4.4
pycosat                0.6.3
pycparser              2.18
Pygments               2.2.0
pymongo                3.7.1
PyNaCl                 1.2.1
pyOpenSSL              18.0.0
pyperclip              1.6.2
PySocks                1.6.8
python-dateutil        2.7.3
pytz                   2018.5
pyzmq                  17.1.0
requests               2.19.1
ruamel-yaml            0.15.37
s3transfer             0.1.13
scipy                  1.1.0
setuptools             40.0.0
six                    1.11.0
torchfile              0.1.0
tornado                5.1
urllib3                1.23
visdom                 0.1.8.4
websocket-client       0.48.0
wheel                  0.31.1
zmq                    0.0.0
```

`pip list` in Leaf (kivy is found here too):

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
asn1crypto             0.24.0
bcrypt                 3.1.4
bitarray               0.8.3
boto                   2.49.0
boto3                  1.7.74
botocore               1.10.74
certifi                2018.4.16
cffi                   1.11.5
chardet                3.0.4
click                  6.7
coloredlogs            10.0
cryptography           2.3
Cython                 0.28.2
docutils               0.14
ffmpeg-python          0.1.15
ffmpy                  0.2.2
future                 0.16.0
humanfriendly          4.16.1
idna                   2.7
jmespath               0.9.3
Kivy                   1.10.1
Kivy-Garden            0.1.4
mysql-connector-python 8.0.11
numpy                  1.15.0
paramiko               2.4.1
Pillow                 5.2.0
pip                    10.0.1
protobuf               3.6.0
pyasn1                 0.4.4
pycparser              2.18
Pygments               2.2.0
pymongo                3.7.1
PyNaCl                 1.2.1
pyOpenSSL              18.0.0
pyperclip              1.6.2
python-dateutil        2.7.3
pytz                   2018.5
pyzmq                  17.1.0
requests               2.19.1
s3transfer             0.1.13
scipy                  1.1.0
setuptools             40.0.0
six                    1.11.0
torchfile              0.1.0
tornado                5.1
umbopython             0.3
urllib3                1.23
visdom                 0.1.8.4
websocket-client       0.48.0
wheel                  0.31.1
zmq                    0.0.0
```

And:

```
roychang@ThinkPad-T480:~$ which pip
/home/roychang/miniconda3/bin/pip
roychang@ThinkPad-T480:~$ act Leaf
(Leaf) roychang@ThinkPad-T480:~$ which pip
/home/roychang/miniconda3/envs/Leaf/bin/pip
```

**LAST UPDATE (PROBABLY)**:

Still not solved.
But don't know why python is separated now.

Tried to uninstall Kivy under Leaf, then Kivy disappeared from both pip list.
I then re-install it under Leaf, and only Leaf got Kivy now.

Comment: Please show the script that uses some packages in this list. That behavior is not correct, and shouldn't happen. Python does not "fetch packages" from the base environment

Comment: @darthbith I have updated some description maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a conda environment yes, but you need to activate. Use

```
jalazbe@DESKTOP:~$ conda activate Leaf
```

You may only use it if the name of the environment is on the left side of your prompt and

```
(Leaf) jalazbe@DESKTOP:~$
```

If you now execute

```
(Leaf) jalazbe@DESKTOP:~$ conda list
```

Then you will see the minimal libraries that conda need to run python. 
To install new libraries use

```
(Leaf) jalazbe@DESKTOP:~$ conda install name-of-library
# example 
(Leaf) jalazbe@DESKTOP:~$ conda install pandas
```

.

I recommend you read some more info at [conda](https://conda.io/docs/)

Comment: I have updated some description upon, it might be useful.

Comment: "Beware that executing conda install without any environment active will make that library accesible to all environments" -> This is not true, I suggest you edit your answer to remove this statement.